# Computing the Galois Group of $\mathbb{Q}\left(2^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Compute the Galois Group of $\mathbb{Q}\left(2^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
I need to see where exactly the basis elements are being mapped.
I refered MORANDI and got to know that the any $\mathbb{Q}-$automorphism will permute the roots .
So does that mean that each such permutation will give me one $\mathbb{Q}-$automorphism?

How do I get a basis for this extension?
Since I am starting galois theory I would request to give an easy explaination without using the symmetric groups here.
I refered other answers but wasn't able to understand.

Comment: It's a bit misleading to call it the "Galois group". $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Galois extension, so usually we just call it the automorphism group and write it as $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})/\mathbb{Q})$.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $\sqrt[4]2$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-2$.
The roots of $f$ are $\sqrt[4]2,i\sqrt[4]2,-\sqrt[4]2,-i\sqrt[4]2$.

Let $\sigma\in\newcommand\Gal{\operatorname{Gal}}\Gal(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)/\Bbb Q)$.
Then $\sigma(\sqrt[4]2)$ is a root of $f$.
Since $\sigma(\sqrt[4]2)\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)\subseteq\Bbb R$, we have $\sigma(\sqrt[4]2)\in\{\sqrt[4]2,-\sqrt[4]2\}$.
Since $\sigma$ is dermined by $\sigma(\sqrt[4]2)$, it follows that $\Gal(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)/\Bbb Q)$ has order two, hence it's isomorphic to the cyclic group of oder $2$.

Comment: I mistakenly downvoted your answer because I misunderstood the question (I thought it was asking for the Galois group of the polynomial $x^4-2$). If you edit your answer so I can change my vote, I will upvote it.

Comment: @Ben I've edited my answer, thank'you